# Condição CSS para quando não tiver SRC na imagem

Tags: css, css3

Preciso que, quando uma imagem não tenha o atributo `src`, o css reconheça isso automaticamente e oculte aquele elemento com `display:none`

Qual é o seletor que devo utilizar para fazer isso?

Exemplo:

```
 <img src="tem_imagem" class="image" />
 <img class="image" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
img[src=""], img:not([src]) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="">
<img src="https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
<img class="teste" border="1">
```

Comment: Mas se realmente não existir o atributo src, vai funcionar?

Comment: Vai sim. Vou por no snippet.

Comment: Acho que no caso do "sem src" não funciona. Se você colocar por padrão uma classe nessa imagem e deixar um border por exemplo, será exibida. Acho que para deixar a resposta correta seria `.minha-imagem[src=""],.minha-imagem:not([src])`. Aqui só funcionou assim.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize um [seletor de atributo](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), e a pseudo-classe [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot):

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
.no-src {
  background-color: #00f;
}
.empty-src {
  background-color: #0f0;
}

img[src=""],
img:not([src]) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img class="no-src"/>
<img src="" class="empty-src"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

Coloca um display none em TODAS as suas imgs e da display block nas que possuem src:

```
img[src] {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Gambiarra nível master